# Wrap label tags around Checkboxes and Radio buttons

Tags: solspace-freeform

Is there a way to wrap label tags around radio and checkbox buttons. I am trying to use bootstrap inline form to make it look better but I can't find a good way to handle it.

```
{freeform:field:field_1 backspace="2" wrapper_open=""
wrapper_close=""
row_wrapper_open=""
row_wrapper_close="
input_wrapper_close=""
label_wrapper_open="<label class='radio-inline'>"
label_wrapper_close="</label>"}
```

The above code is an example of some of the ways I tried to handle this. but this gives me a clickable label tag that doesn't select anything.

```
<label>
    <input type="radio" name="field_1"> Field 1
</label>
```

Is the result I would like.

Answer (score 0):

? You can just construct your own form, you don't need to use tags with FreeForm.

```
{exp:freeform:form form_name="contact" return="freeform-return/%%entry_id%%"}

<label for="first_name">
    Name
    <input type="text" name="name">
</label>

<label for="submit">
    Submit
    <input type="submit" name="submit">
</label>

{/exp:freeform:form}
```

This  creates a valid form that submits to FreeForm and returns you to url-root.com/freeform-return/666.

**Edit** if that is the case (responding to your comment), why don't you use the fields as variable pairs?

https://solspace.com/docs/freeform/form/#variable_pairs

From the docs:

```
{freeform:all_form_fields}
<p>
    <label>{freeform:field_label}</label>
    {freeform:field_output}
    {if freeform:field_type == 'text'}hello!{/if}
</p>
{/freeform:all_form_fields}
```

Will this magic work for the solution you want?

Comment: The only downside to that approach is the fact that if the customer changes the value of the checkbox or adds another one I would need to manually add it to the template so I want a way to dynamically generate it using the CMS.

Comment: I updated my answer.

Comment: Hmm, but I don't believe `{freeform:field_output}` includes an `id` attribute, which is required when using the `for` attribute on a `label` element.